# nVidia Shadowplay recording not working with 10bpc colordepth

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-geforce-experience, shadowplay

I am using Shadowplay and have an Odyssey G7 (32").
When I put the color-depth to 10 bpc (from 8 bpc) in the nvidia control panel everything works normal
except when I activate one of the two recording-features of Shadowplay (Save last seconds or normal recording).
If I activate Shadow-Play recording some (maybe all) windows I have open will flicker and recording will deactivate after a couple of seconds.
If I activate "status" in shadowplay hud I get this symbol:

[image: Picture]

Comment: Is there a specific reason you would like to use 10 bpc instead of 8? One thing to try is after setting it to 10, restart your computer and see if the problem persists.